# How do I use the Thread class to execute an arithmetic-like method?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, module

How do I execute this code inside a Thread object?

I want continuous execution, but I a have poor knowledge working with Thread objects. I have a `Number` class, which receives a number as a parameter.

If the number is even, do something, if odd, do something else, eventually what I am after is a continuous evaluation of the number within this framework of conditions with 'number' getting to 1. All elements are to be stored inside an array and querying the `array.last` to return 1.

```
class Number
  attr_accessor :x
  def initialize (number)
    @x=[] 
    if (number % 2 == 0)
      @x << number/2

    elsif (number % 2 != 0)
      @x << (number*3)+1
    end
    print  @x.to_s.concat(" ") // unable to continue

  end
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what your input and output data is supposed to be?  Nothing in your post screams out "threading is the right solution to this problem".

Comment: Ok, first off, it may not be the case that ever thread is needed. My input is a number, which has to go through the even/odd conditions and looping through these eventually evaluate to 1. That would be the output. Given 22 divided by 2 result in 11 which in hand executes code corresponding to the (number %2 !=0) etc

Comment: This is not a threading problem, this is a recursion problem.

Comment: Thank you. Do i have to use a conditional loop and a flag? until i get the desired result, or how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
def recurse(x, a = [])
  a << x
  return a if x == 1
  if x % 2 == 0
    recurse(x/2, a)
  else
    recurse((x*3 + 1)/2, a)
  end
end

recurse 7
=> [7, 11, 17, 26, 13, 20, 10, 5, 8, 4, 2, 1]

recurse 12
=> [12, 6, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, i get the idea. However, on my machine this code does not compile. Yet, it does help.

Comment: When you say it does not compile, what do you mean?  I ran it on irb and it went fine.  Note that this is just a method, not part of an underlying class.  What error are you getting?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby

    class R

    def recurse(x, a = [])
      a << x
      if x % 2 == 0
      recurse(x/2, a)
       else
       recurse((x*3 + 1)/2, a)
       end
      end
      end


x = R.new
x.recurse 20

    puts x` gives me a stack level to deep error, possibly because i am calling the same method within  a method of the same name. this is however done in an editor , same for irb -- stack level to deep

Comment: My answer was missing a very important line.  My apologies.  I've corrected it above.